# Why is Office 2013 Home and Business for personal use only?

Tags: license, microsoft-office-2013

I have just bought Office 2013 Home and Business, because I want to use it commercially. Now I'm asked to download Office (the product is only a key card), but the [Microsoft website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2808266/en) says

> **Important** These Office suites are for home use on one PC and can't be installed on multiple PCs.

Why is it for home use when it is called "Home and Business"? Can I use it commercially or not? If not, I would have to return it to the vendor.

Comment: All that statement is saying is that the license does not allow you to activate the same license on multiple computers.

Comment: @Ramhound: that's the second part. The first part is "are for home use"

Comment: I can't comment on a "second part" that I can't read myself.  The comment you quoted says what I explained, the license can only be activated on a single computer, there is a process to deactivate that computer but multiple computers cannot be activated at once unlike other versions of Office 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft advertises Home and Business](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/buy-microsoft-office-home-business-2013-FX102918379.aspx) as having "commercial use rights", and the version comparison says it is for "home or business use". It seems as though it is authorized for commercial use; if I had to guess, I'd say they *probably* meant "Home and *Student* is home use only", or copied some old boilerplate, or something. They also had Professional under that blanket statement, after all, and I can't imagine Office Professional being restricted to non-professional use.

If you want to be safe, though, I'd advise contacting Microsoft and asking them directly.

Answer (score 0):

if my memory doesn't plays trick on me, the 'license' that you acquired can be used in any Office DISC or IMAGE (ISO) version, and what it do is 'restrict' what 'parts' of office you can use, and in how many computers, for example: i have a Office Pro Plus DISC and i installed it on my PC, but i DON'T HAVE a 'license', to use it, so i go to the store and bought a 'home and student' license, so when i input my license code in Office Pro Plus, it automatically changes to Home and Student' because the serial that i got from the store

so if you have a 'home and business' license, no matther of what the disc says it will use your license as base and will transform you office accordly

furthermore, the office licences are restricted, some are for 1 PC only, as example the 'home and student' licences can be bought for 1 pc or 3 pc's, so if i'm not wrong, your license should say for how many computers is it

i'm a PC technician, so i use a 'Volume' license, it allow me to activate office in a fixed number of PC's, and then those ones can be validated through an online server, this method is largely used in big enterprises where they need to deploy hundred or thousands of PC's with office and needs to do it in 'hassle free' way